# Override Inline Style

Tags: css

I've read the other questions on here about overriding inline style imported from Javascript and I feel like I'm missing something here.

The iframe and current code can be seen at 
https://www.timedoutescape.com/waiver/
(you can put random first / last name and email to get to the signing interface I'm trying to style)

The current code is --

```
<div id="signingSpace" style="background-color: white; height: 300px; width: 819px;" class="kbw-signature"><canvas width="815" height="296">Your browser doesn't support signing</canvas></div>
```

And I'm trying to override it with

```
#signingSpace[style] {
    height: 100px !important;
}
```

Any advice?

Comment: take away `[style]` and what happens?

Comment: You don't need `[style]` - IDs are unique, so it's redundant

Comment: Removing [style] doesn't fix it since the current style is inlined. So that style overrides any ID properties